# App crashes whenever I try to push a view controller on a UITableViewCell click

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS app used to work well until some time ago, but suddenly it crashes whenever I click on a table cell and try to push another view controller.

After doing a lot of researches, I understood that it is because the table view is destroyed **before** the push happens, but I can't figure out where and why.

The app is an old project written in Objective-C and using non-ARC mode.

The error message was not clear and varied in every crash, so I tried setting the `animated` flag to `NO` of `pushViewController` function, and now I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` every time.

How can I narrow down the location of the error and fix this irritating bug?

<del>**UPDATE**: One more piece of information. For other view controllers that have `xib` files, they are pushed successfully. This only happens to those view controllers that are generated by code.</del>

Here is the code snippet for pushing view controllers:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSIndexPath* pagePath = [[self.pageIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:indexPath.section] indexPathByAddingIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *viewController = [[ContentStore contentStore] viewControllerForPage:pagePath];

  if (viewController) {
      NSString *title = [[ContentStore contentStore] titleForPage:pagePath];
      UIViewController *testVC = [[NSClassFromString(viewController) alloc] init];
      testVC.navigationItem.title = title;
      NSLog(@"%@", self.parentVC.navigationController.viewControllers);
      [self.parentVC.navigationController pushViewController:testVC animated:NO];
  } else {
      NSString *remoteUrl = [[ContentStore contentStore] remoteURLForPage:pagePath];
      DownloadManager *manager = [DownloadManager sharedManager];
      if ( remoteUrl && ( ![manager isRemoteResourceMarkedForDownload:remoteUrl] || ![manager isRemoteResourceDownloaded:remoteUrl] ) ) {
          [[DownloadManager sharedManager] markRemoteResource:remoteUrl forDownload:YES];
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTables" object:nil];
      } else {
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangePage"
                                                              object:nil
                                                            userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pagePath,@"ChangePage",
                                                                      @"YES", @"Animate",@"YES",@"Remapped",@"NO",@"Sandbox",nil]];
      }
  }
}
```

In the above code snippet, `if (viewController)` clause <del>does not</del> also results in the crash (where the corresponding view controller `xib`'s and classes exist).

And this is the `changePage` notification handler in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)changePage:(NSNotification*)notification {

  NSIndexPath* pathIndex = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"ChangePage"];
  NSString*    shortcut  = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Shortcut"];
  bool         animate   = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Animate"] boolValue];
  bool         sandbox   = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Sandbox"] boolValue];
  //bool         remapped  = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Remapped"] boolValue];
  NSString*    words     = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Words"];

 //NSLog(@"changePage: %@ animate=%d sandbox=%d ", pathIndex,animate,sandbox );

  if ( pathIndex.length==0 ) {
    pathIndex = [[ContentStore contentStore] pathIndexForShortcutId:shortcut];
    if ( pathIndex.length==0 ) {
      pathIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0];
    }
  }

  [Flurry logEvent:@"ChangePage" withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pathIndex forKey:@"Path"]];

  NSUInteger selectedTab = [pathIndex indexAtPosition:0];

  UINavigationController* nvc = nil;
  if ( self.tabBarController.viewControllers.count>selectedTab )
    nvc = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:selectedTab];
  if ( !nvc ) return; // Exit for non-existing tabs.

  NSMutableArray *stack =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nvc.viewControllers];

  // Pop viewcontrollers until pathIndex has a partial match.
  while(true) {
    BaseViewController* last = [stack lastObject];
    if (!last) break;
    if ( pathIndex.length < last.pageIndexPath.length ) {
      [stack removeLastObject];
    } else {
      bool match = YES;
      for(NSUInteger position=0;position<last.pageIndexPath.length;position++) {
        if ( [pathIndex indexAtPosition:position] != [last.pageIndexPath indexAtPosition:position] ) {
          match = NO;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (match) {
        break;
      } else {
        [stack removeLastObject];
      }
    }
  }

  for(NSUInteger position=((BaseViewController*)[stack lastObject]).pageIndexPath.length;position+1<pathIndex.length;position+=2) {
    BaseViewController* last = [stack lastObject];
    NSIndexPath* newPageIndex = [[last.pageIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:[pathIndex indexAtPosition:position]] indexPathByAddingIndex:[pathIndex indexAtPosition:position+1]];
    BaseViewController* newVC = [self createViewControllerWithPageIndexPath:newPageIndex parentViewController:[stack lastObject]];
    if ( [newVC isKindOfClass:WebViewController.class] ) {
      [(WebViewController*)newVC setSandboxed:sandbox];
      [(WebViewController*)newVC setWords:words];
    }
    if ( !newVC ) break; // Fail in path, stop
    [stack addObject:newVC];
  }

  // Set the stack
  [nvc setViewControllers:stack animated:animate];

  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedTab];
  [self showDisclaimer];
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you push the VC? is the vc an iVar or property?

Comment: @Joshua I have added the code snippets. Thanks for your interest and time.

Comment: have you enabled zombie?

Comment: @Joshua No, how do I do that?

Comment: edit the scheme you are using then under diagnostics check "enable zombie objects" so when it does crash it will point to where the zombie object is

Comment: @Joshua I tried enabling the zombie and this message appeared: `[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance`. It seems like I am getting somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: yup seems that its not on the pushing of VC

Comment: @Joshua Any suggestion on how to move forward from here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118197/discussion-between-joshua-and-technophyle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed the issue.

I enabled the zombie and found that the error message - `[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance`, so I started looking at the code where there might be poor memory management and found the line that was causing the issue:

In the `RootViewController.m` (that all the view controllers are inherited from),

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  ...

  /* Search button on the nav bar */
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui_tabbar_search.png"] autorelease];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchButtonClicked:)];
}
```

So I was `autoreleasing` the image resource, and setting it as the navigation bar item.

I know it's a silly answer, but I hope someone might get help from it.